# Need help in creating an implementation without generics

Tags: c#

I have the following code. Note that I have a generic method `AsJson<T>`. Is it possible to replace that method with a non-generics implementation. The reason is that an instance of the Interface already knows which class it belongs to and I dont want to "unnecessarily" pass the T parameter.

```
internal interface Interface
{
    JToken Parameters { get; }

    protected abstract static string NameIdentifier { get; }

    public sealed JToken AsJson<T>() where T : Interface
    {
        var result = new JObject
        {
            { "Name", T.NameIdentifier },
            { "Parameters", this.Parameters },
        };
        return result;
    }

    // HOW TO IMPLEMENT the following instead, WITHOUT USING GENERICS?
    //public sealed JToken AsJson()
    //{ 
    //    // ?
    //}
}

internal class Implementer : Interface
{
    static string Interface.NameIdentifier => "Impl1";

    JToken Interface.Parameters => new JObject { { "Variable1", "Some value" } };
}

// Many implementations of Interface exist in different classes similar to Implementer (given here purely as an example)

public static class ImplementerFactory
{
    public Interface Create(params string[] args)
    {
        // based on the args, create and return an instance of one of the many classes implementing the interface
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Interface instance = ImplementerFactory.Create(args); // I am unaware which class's instance is returned here, just that it is of type Interface
        var json = instance.AsJson(); // THIS IS HOW I WOULD LIKE TO CALL IT. 
    }
}
```

I tried of course to create a generics based method, but I would like to avoid that.

**NOTE:**
The `NameIdentifier` property could be of a custom type other than string and is really **a class-level property and therefore has to be static as it has the same value for all the instances of the same class**. Perhaps the following "over-simplification" would explain. Think of the Interface as being the type representing an Animal. The implementing classes are of the types say,
Dog, Fish, and so on... The list of JSONs that I wish to extract are

```
    [
    {
      "Name": "Dog",
      "Parameters":
      {
        "Is a pet": true,
        "OwnerName": Robert,
        "Collar Number": XYZ34
      } 
    },
    {
      "Name": "Fish",
      "Parameters":
      {
        "Lives in ocean": true,
        "Number of dorsal fins": 2,
        "Species": "Alpha Beta"
      } 
    },
    {
      "Name": "Dog",
      "Parameters":
      {
        "Is a pet": false,
      } 
    }
]
```

Comment: Could you show us how exactly the non-generic method would be called? Because you can't call `AsJson<T>()` on an instance of type `Implementer` anyway. It must be typed as `Interface` to have the method available.

Comment: Why not just add `JToken AsJson() => ((Interface)this).AsJson<Implementer>();` to `Implementer`?

Comment: Fair enough and thanks for the quick reply @GoodNightNerdPride . I have added a few more lines to clarify your query. See the last class Program- there I would like to call the AsJson() on the instance created by the factory class. You will note that in the Program class I really do not know which class is being instantiated

Comment: May I ask why you want to do all that when you could simply use polymorphic deserialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention why `NameIdentifier` is static, so I assume that's actually not needed. Making it an instance property simplifies everything quite a bit:

```cs
internal interface Interface
{
    JToken Parameters { get; }

    protected string NameIdentifier { get; }

    public sealed JToken AsJson()
    {
        var result = new JObject
        {
            { "Name", NameIdentifier },
            { "Parameters", this.Parameters },
        };
        return result;
    }
}

internal class Implementer : Interface
{
    string Interface.NameIdentifier => "Impl1";

    JToken Interface.Parameters => new JObject { { "Variable1", "Some value" } };
}
```

I suppose another option is to make `Interface` an abstract class that takes the value of `NameIdentifier` via its constructor instead.

Comment: Well, that's the challenge really :-). The `NameIdentifier` property is really a class-level property and therefore **has to be static** as it has the same value for all the instances of the same class. I did not wish to pollute the problem description giving too many details but I have tried to explain it now in the original problem description.

Comment: All instances of Implementer have the same value for NameIdentifier, as it is a get-only property

Comment: True @HansKeﬆing. What I meant was (based on the **Note** suffix in the problem description), the value of `NameIdentifier` is Dog for all implementations through the Dog class, is Fish for all implementations through the Fish class and so on. The class `Implementer` has been provided only as a sample- there are many such `Implementer` classes, each with their unique value of `NameIdentifier`.

Comment: @SoumyaDutta I think you are misunderstanding. All instances of my version of `Implementer` will have `"Impl1"` as a value for `NameIdentifier`. And I might very well define a second implementation, say `Implementer2`, and make its instances have `"Impl2"` as a value for `NameIdentifier`. This is exactly what you are asking albeit not in the most efficient way since each instance will have an additional string reference stored with it on the heap (the different string values will be interned though).

Comment: I see your point @GoodNightNerdPride. Indeed, if the `NameIdentifier` is a String type (as described in the problem), having it as non- static will indeed reuse instances of the string from the heap. But that is a special case. The objective of my question is how to get the solution **when using a static member**- consider the case when `NameIdentifier` is of a custom type. Then it will create instances of that custom type for every `Implementer` instance, which is wasteful, memory- wise.

Comment: @SoumyaDutta 1) The default implementation of `AsJson()` in `Interface` *needs* a type parameter to access `NameIdentifier` otherwise the compiler would not know which implementation of `Interface` it should refer to. 2) The client code does not know which implementation of `Interface` it is currently working with and hence cannot pass a type parameter to `AsJson()`. There is no way to reconcile these two requirements with C# at compile-time. You *must* take another approach. Either make the property non-static (not optimal) or try reflection (even less optimal).

Comment: Thanks @GoodNightNerdPride- you have confirmed my suspicions therefore that the problem has no solution as long as `NameIdentifier` is a static member. I shall now mark this as resolved (By Design).